# How can EJBs use spring boot beans?

Tags: spring-boot, glassfish-3

Using the idea that we found in:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html#ejb-implementation-ejb3

we wanted to use interceptor in order to access spring boot beans from an EJBs. But the problem is, the example of the documentation uses a new context.

How can the EJBs access the spring boot context?

We tried this:

```
public class MySpringActuatorMetricsCoreTestInterceptor extends SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor {

        //Spring boot application context
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    @Override
    protected BeanFactory getBeanFactory(Object target) {
        return applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    }

}
```

And the EBJ looks like this:

```
// ejb
@Stateless
// spring
@Interceptors(MySpringActuatorMetricsCoreTestInterceptor.class)
public class FirstBean {
[...]
```

The problem is: application context is not already initialized because EJBs initialization happens before and as a consequence -> null pointer exception.

We think there are two options:
- We get the application context somehow from the spring boot.
- We can give the context that we could create by MySpringActuatorMetricsCoreTestInterceptor to the spring boot context.

Is there any solution? another option?

We are using Glassfish 3.1

Thanks!

Comment: EJBs and Spring Boot seem orthogonal to me.  My preference is Spring and Spring Boot. Ditch the EJBs.

Comment: I have not found a way either, the best bet probably would be to expose the services as rest services using spring boot and spring rest.
Consuming ejbs in spring boot however is possible.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I found a way as it seems:
I just added a beanRefContext.xml to my classpath:

    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
        "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans_2_0.dtd">
    <beans>
       <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
        <constructor-arg value="classpath*:simpleContext.xml" />
      </bean>
   </beans>`

Which references a new applicationContext file named simpleContext.xml also in my classpath:

```
...
<!-- Enable annotation support within our beans -->
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.path" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />
```

...

Now I was able to inject spring boot services into my EJB:

```
@Stateless(name = "RightsServiceEJB")
@Remote
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class RightsServiceEJB implements IRightsServiceEJB {

   @Autowired
   ExampleService exampleService;

   @Override
   public String sayHello() {
      return exampleService.sayHello();
   }
```

}

This however is for now a small hello world Example, I am not sure if the Spring service still can reference resources initialized by Spring boot. This will need further testing on my side.

Comment: Ok I just evaluated this method against a service which uses a db, and it seems to work, the service still accesses my db and returns a correct value.

Comment: Ok as it seems, you have to add the entire component scan for your spring boot application. Spring boot then starts a second time for the ejb infrastructure with its own application context. That way the configuration is shared over the ejb and the application instances. However you have to have that in mind that you now deal with two separate application contexts in your running application, one for the main app and one for the ejbs.

Comment: Unfortunately, SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor has been removed in Spring 5 : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21361